# How to return multiple data separated with comma in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a sheet with two folders: **Teachers** and **Discipline**.

I'm trying to get the **Discipline.ID** at the **Teacher.Discipline** cell by using the following function:

```
                   =JOIN(",";FILTER(Discipline!A:A;Discipline!C:C=B2))
```

[as you can see it in this sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jwo2ZtcrOJlgqk-oB0S4cIQqPLt7TWA_rw1ZYUyv_rI/edit?usp=sharing).

The problem is, it works for **Disciplines** with only one **Teacher**, but when I try to filter the **Teacher.Name** at **Discipline.Teacher** with multiple teacher, it either returns the **Discipline.ID** when the name appears before the comma, or returns a NULL value if the name is after the comma (at **Discipline.Teacher**).

Is there any function that can return these values without this comma issue? (Needs to be specifcally in Google Sheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C2 try

```
=JOIN(",";FILTER(Discipline!A:A; regexmatch(Discipline!C:C; B2)))
```

and fill down.

Hope that helps?